# pass an array to a function to query database in PP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to pass an array with varying number of column names and the table to query database.

```
public function get_list() {

    $list = func_get_args();
    $table = array_pop($list);
    $fields = implode(', ', $list);

    $sql = "SELECT $fields FROM $table";
    $data = array();
    try {
      $dbi = db::getInstance();
      $stmt = $dbi->data->prepare($sql); 
      $stmt->execute();
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data[]=$row[$fields];
      }
      return $data;     
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) { 
      die($ex); 
    }  
  }
```

The query gets the table and the right column, if there is only one.
But, if the array includes more than one column, it says:

> Undefined index: value1, value2

Is there a valid way to use a comma separated string to query more than one column?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `$data[] = $row;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the `$fields` in the loop.  Your query will only return the fields that you specified. So your code would be:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

But here are two ways to get the data as you are showing.  Just assign in the loop:

```
while ($data[] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {}
```

Or use a function to get all the rows:

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

However, if I was going to take this approach I would pass in the table and fields (as an array) as specified arguments:

```
public function get_list($table, $fields)
```

To use the results outside of the function with dynamic fields, you would need to loop `$rows` to get them:

```
foreach ($this->model->get_list($fields, $table) as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
        echo "$field contains $value";
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to return an array to loop in the main function. Like this: 'foreach($this->model->get_list($field,$table) as $row) { echo $row;}' Can you tell me the best way to do that

Comment: Ahhhh! Now i got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You seem confused about that function. Do you know a better way to pass varying number of column names to a funtion that returns the result of a database query?